# Javascript date formate conversion issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this code:

```
click: function () {

datevalue = (this.x); //Returns 198

var dateTimeString = moment(datevalue).format("DDMMY"); //Returns 01011970


}
```

My problem is that dateTimeString is returning the format as 01011970 (so... 01-01-1970) and I need it to return the year in just 2 digits (70 in the case).

I've tried **.format("DDMMY")** and **.format("DDMMyy")** but none of them work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried  .format("YY") ??

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/  `YY`... and absolute worst case, your date is just a string, you can always get the full 4 digit year then use a string operation to extract the last two characters.

Comment: YY on it's own will only return 70 I need dd mm YY for example: 010170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried .format("DDMMY") and .format("DDMMyy")

Why would you do this? You want the year only, not the day and month.

---

Just format in the format you want:

```
var dateTimeString = moment(datevalue).format("YY");
```

---

According to your comment above, try

```
var dateTimeString = moment(datevalue).format("DDMMYY");
```

Comment: I need dd mm YY not just the year. But at the moment the year is coming out in 4 digits and I need it in 2. For example: 01 01 70 instead of 01 01 1970